# Clone a React component that implements forwardRef

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Lets say I have a base component that uses `forwardRef` like so:

```
const BaseMessage = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => (
   <div ref={ref}>
      {props.icon}
      <h2>{props.title}</h2>
      <p>{props.message}</p>
   </div>
)
```

Now I want to create a second component, `ErrorMessage` that is essentially a copy of the `BaseMessage` but with a predefined value for `props.icon`, such that the `icon` prop is not needed to be set. Otherwise, its an exact copy of `BaseMessage`.

```
<ErrorMessage title="Oops!" message="Something went wrong when submitting the form. Please try again." />
```

I don't want to have to do this, since it feels weird to have two layers of `forwardRef` going on here:

```
const ErrorMessage = React.forwardRef(({icon, ...props}, ref) => (
   <BaseMessage ref={ref} icon={<svg></svg>} {...props} />
))
```

Is there a way I can make a clone/copy of `BaseMessage` without having to reimplement `forwardRef` for `ErrorMessage` as well? I know there are utils out there like `withProps` from `recompose` but I'd like to avoid using a library if I can.

Comment: How about default props :) or you can accept only props and de-structure on the next line and explicitly return. BaseMessage.defaultProps = {icon:''} should work too

Comment: @RahilAhmad the idea is that `ErrorMessage` would not expose the `icon` prop. If I just set `defaultProps = { icon: 'thing' }` then the prop is still available to be overridden.

Answer (score 0):

Try [cloneElememt](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#cloneelement)

```js
React.cloneElement(BaseMessage, { icon: '' })
```